# Drinfeld modules and shtukas

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $\rho$ be a Drinfeld module on $\mathbb F_q(T)$ defined by
$$\rho_T=\sum_{î=0}^da_i(T)F^i\qquad(a_i\in\mathbb F_q(T))$$
where $F$ is the $q$-Frobenius.
Let $f$ be the shtuka function associated to $\rho$. My basic question: is $f$ a rational function with coefficient in $\mathbb F_q(T)$ and how to determine it explicitely from the $a_i$'s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shtuka functions only exist for rank 1 Drinfeld $A$-modules over some $A$-field $L$. For the case $A = \mathbb{F}_q[T]$, the shtuka function is simply $T-\gamma(T)$ up to a scalar multiple, where $\gamma:A\to L$ is the structure map. In general case, it might be trickier to determine, but basically the idea is to look at the Shtuka-Drinfeld modules correspondence and roughly speaking shtuka function is determined by the Frobenius action.